# Superuser's software says “'cores' are new tags” instead of “'cores' is a new tag” -- fixable?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Superuser says to me:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because:
>
> ```
> * new users can't create tags; 'cores' are new tags
> ```

Shouldn't this say "'cores' is a new tag"?

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it should suggest the correct grammar based on the number of attempted tags instead of just assuming it is the multiple.

Comment: That was exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate, many times over.